# How can I access CancellationPending for this thread beyond the BackgroundWorker class?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a Windows service that creates a number of BackgroundWorkers. The DoWork handler of these BackgroundWorkers just contains SomeObject.DoSomeWork() and the method (i.e. DoSomeWork) does not take any reference to the BackgroundWorker. The blocking work happens many layers deeper. In the method with the blocking work I want to add logic to test CancellationPending of the owning BackgroundWorker. How???

I don't want to refactor all the classes to pass a reference to the BackgroundWorker, I want to be able to write something like this;

```
(BackgroundWorker(Thread.CurrentThread)).CancellationPending
```

But this obviously doesn't work because BackgroundWorker is not a thread itself.

I haven't tried anything because I haven't thought of anything to try. I've Googled a lot and read a lot but not found anything to point me in the right direction. It might be the case that it's not possible (at least not possible without getting too hacky) in which case I'll have to think of a different approach to the problem, but I need someone cleverer than me to tell me it's not possible :)

Comment: `Func<bool> cancelCheck = delegate { return backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending; };`.  Pass cancelCheck to the deeper layers so it can periodically call it to check if the property has turned *true*.  Or use the Task class instead, it supports CancellationToken.

Comment: @HansPassant The question does specifically state "I don't want to refactor all the classes to pass a reference ...".

Comment: That comment wasn't meant for you, just to programmers that find this question and want to do it the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hack to do this. Only use this if there is no other choice. You can use a thread local variable to make the `BackgroundWorker` available anywhere on the current thread.

```
[ThreadStatic]
static BackgroundWorker bw;
```

Then, you need to maintain this variable:

```
try {
 bw = ...;
 DoSomeWork();
}
finally { bw = null; }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this is hacky - is it just exposing the full BackgroundWorker object this way? If the ThreadStatic static member was private and the value of CancellationPending was exposed through a simple static method that seems OK to me. Obviously not as good as doing things properly in the first place though :)

Comment: By threading (mutable) state through the call chain like this you create non-local interactions and dependencies. None of them are visible in the source code or through tooling. This is a source of bugs and misunderstandings. TLS is really nasty from that standpoint. HttpContext.Current has the same problems. It constantly causes bugs in threaded code.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a collection `Dictionary<MyObject, BackgroundWorker>` where you store your objects and background workers references and then an extension method :

```
public static void CancelWork(this MyObjectObject myObj)
{
  var kvp = dictionary.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Key.equals(myObj));

  if(kvp.Key == null) return;

  // TODO
  // Call the background worker cancellation from the kvp.Value
}
```

This extension method could be called from your object as :

```
this.CancelWork();
```

Comment: CancellationPending is a readonly property of the BackgroundWorker class. It gets set by calling the CancelAsync() method.

Comment: Sorry, didn't have a Visual Studio near me. I though of setting the PendingCancellationToken to true. Anyway, I think you got what I meant.

I edited my answer for a pseudo-code cancellation call.

Comment: My problem is not calling Cancel, it is reading CancellationPending, and obviously it all needs to be thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly as in the @Panda's answer, you could have a static `Dictionary<int, BackgroundWorker> workers;` collection and fill it in the start of your `DoWork` handler:

```
workers[Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId] = sender as BackgroundWorker;
```

and then use it in your `DoSomeWork` like this:

```
bw = workers[Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId];
// use bw.CancellationPending
```

but be aware of synchronizing this collection, it might be better to use `ConcurrentDictionary`. And one more thing, you should be sure that your `DoWork` handler runs only in one thread for this to work.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you and @Panda are suggesting. However, it will require care to make sure the approach is thread safe (by definition my DoWork handler runs on multiple threads). I think @Usr has the right idea with `[ThreadStatic]`.

Comment: @RhysJones, It seems that this approach and @usr approach are the same in that they work only if your `DoWork`, while started, does not jump over different threads. If not, you have to supply and propagate some id or just `BackgroundWorker` to all your `DoSomeWork`s or else how they would know what the thread that started `DoWork` was.

Comment: ManagedThreadId might technically be OK to use but I don't like that approach - if I was to refactor heavily and replace BackgroundWorkers with something else then ManagedThreadId might no longer be safe. Usr's suggestion of using [ThreadStatic] means that my blocking code can just read a static member of my WorkerThread class to get the BackgroundWorker that was stored at the the start of DoWork.

Comment: OK, and that really looks better)